# How can I call a one func(class) which defined after current func(class) ? python

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have two classes in one file:

```
class A_Serializer():
    b = B_Serializer()

class B_Serializer():
    a = A_Serializer()
```

Obviously, `A_Serializer` will raise a not defined error.
Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks a lot.

This problem is silly, because:
If above codes are legal,
two classes will form a ring, call any one will enter an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply assign *after* class is created.

```
class A_Serializer():
    pass

class B_Serializer():
    pass

A_Serializer.b = B_Serializer()
B_Serializer.a = A_Serializer()
```

Comment: It's helpful, but doesn't work for rest framework. Although no error raising, assignment no effect too.

Comment: @Lingbing you need to provide [MCVE] which exposes your issue. Your code snippet wasn't mentioning django at all. That's why I removed this tag from a question. For what I know, my answer completely solves problem shown in question.

Comment: sorry , I create this problem with both python and rest-framework tags, but I don't know why it missed one~